# How to return the reference of a row of a double[,]

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional array that I would like to return a reference of a row of the array in a method so that any changes to this row will be reflected in the original array.  Right now I have the following method, but it is returning new instances of the values because of the doubles being passed around.

```
public double[] GetRowReference(int rowNumber)
{
    double[] output = new double[_allPoints.GetLength(1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < _allPoints.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        output[i] = _allPoints[rowNumber, i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

How can I return this row as a reference instead of the values?

Comment: it is not possible. (unfortunately) you better look for another way for example why not working with 2d array directly?

Comment: another way is to use jagged array so you can return reference of inner arrays, you have to change part of your program though. `double[][] array = new double[2][]; double[] reference = new[] { 4d, 4, 5 }; array[1] = reference; reference[1] = 6;`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I am trying to write my API so that it is easier to understand what the rows mean, hence properties that reference a given row in an overall 2d array.  I have thought about implementing jagged arrays, but figured I was missing something with the 2d array implementation.

Comment: Its possible with jagged arrays (as @M.kazemAkhgary says), but not with multidimensional.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I ended up implementing jagged arrays to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a single dimensional array in which accessing an item accesses the item in the corresponding row of another two dimensional array.

The best that you can do is create your own type that has that logic, and exposes a single dimensional list's API (i.e. through `IList<T>`) in which you map each operation into an appropriate operation on a stored two dimensional list:

```
public class ArrayRow<T> : IList<T>
{
    private T[,] array;
    private int row;
    public ArrayRow(T[,] array, int row)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.row = row;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return array[row, index];
        }
        set
        {
            array[row, index] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return array.GetLength(1); }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            yield return array[row, j];
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    //TODO implement remaining IList<T> methods
}
```